# pylint.vim does not show warnings

Tags: vim, pylint

I just installed pylint and pylint.vim plugin but when pylint is invoked from vim it only shows a code rate and not the warnings.Anyone got any ideas why this is so?

Comment: You're not very specific. Specifying versions of everything can help a lot.

Comment: pylint --version gets you everything in that regard to file a pylint bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably caused by the recent change in pylint output format (which now displays the column number). Have you tried http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script:891 or http://www.held.org.il/blog/2011/08/pylint-vim-plugin-update-0-24-0-support/ ?

Answer (score 0):

was playing around with this and just barely got it to work.
the two lines i changed were:

```
CompilerSet makeprg=(pylint\ -r\ y\ --output-format=parseable\ %)

CompilerSet efm=%f:%l:\ [%t]%m,%f:%l:%m
```

this works with pylint 0.26. 
hopefully this helps.